# not getting the object properties of a node object

Tags: javascript, async-await

so, i am very new to node and express, i ran through a problem like 
here i am importing all other js files like

```
import { User } from './user.js';

class App {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    async init() {
        this.user = await new User();
        this.team = await new Team();
        this.navbar = new Navbar();
        this.tree = new Tree();
        this.settings = await new Settings();
        this.board = await new Board();


        this.ping();
        return this;
    }

    ping() {
        //some functionality
    }
}
```

now creating the object here

```
app = await new App();
console.log('app', app);
```

this gives me

```
app > App {}
```

on clicking the `>` i am getting this

```
>user: User {username: "someusername", roles: Array(1), settings: undefined}
>navbar: Navbar {timerIsRunning: false}
```

how can i access the properties like app.user also JSON.stringify gives me blank `{}`

Comment: Could you paste your user class

Comment: Also the question is not clear and sample code, could you please elaborate more and what is expected. clicking on `>` means what ?

Comment: found the problem.. the problem is before all the object properties get initialized i am trying to get it

Answer (score 0):

Replace constructor in App class by next:

```
  constructor() {
        return (async () => {
            return await this.init();
        })();
    }
```

now creating the object here

```
(async () => {
  const app = await new App();
  console.log("app", app);
})();
```